# Centralized REST API request dispatcher

Tags: c#, rest

Recently I had to implement a Windows Service that connects to the Shopify REST API and pulls essentially everything new into some SQL Server database, on a hourly basis; I've also implemented a small console app off this code, that can query the REST API from command-line.

The Shopify REST API is rate-limited (using the "leaky bucket" method), obviously, so I can't just send all requests involved all at once. The rate limit is per API key, per REST endpoint. When a response is received, the headers include the throttling metadata.

So in order to adhere to best practices, I implemented a `RequestDispatcher` class whose role is to... dispatch requests, and have a way to ensure all responses get handled before the dispatcher gets disposed: clients can do that by invoking the `WaitForCompletion` method, which blocks the current thread until the both `CountdownEvent` counters reach 0.

Clients of this class simply `Enqueue` an `IDispatchedRequest`, and the dispatcher decides when the request is actually issued, using a timer that I've configured to tick 10 times per second (ticks are skipped if throttling metadata warrants waiting a bit).

This is what an `IDispatchedRequest` looks like (that's the non-generic version - there are other variants extending it):

```
public interface IDispatchedRequest
{
    int Retries { get; set; }
    string ResourceName { get; }
    Func<Task> Request { get; }
    Func<object,Task> OnResponse { get; }
}
```

There are various implementations of that interface, notably `DispatchedRequest`, `DispatchedEntityRequest`, `DispatchedPostRequest`, and `DispatchedChildEntititesRequest`. In every case, the idea is to encapsulate a `Func` delegate that returns a `Task<Response<T>>` (I'm using `RestEase` to deal with all the JSON deserialization, so that's a `RestEase.Response<T>`), and a `Func` delegate that takes the `response` and handles it.

I'm pretty happy with the implementation, I find it looks pretty clean in general, but the part that handles exceptions is rather chaotic... yet everything works as intended as far as I can tell.

```
public class RequestDispatcher : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private readonly INotifierService _notifier;
    private readonly int _appId;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public static readonly int ShopifyDefaultBucketCapacity = Settings.Default.ShopifyDefaultBucketCapacity;
    public static readonly int ShopifyPlusBucketCapacity = Settings.Default.ShopifyPlusBucketCapacity;

    private readonly double TicksPerSecond;
    private readonly double _cutoff;

    private CountdownEvent _requestWaitHandle;
    private CountdownEvent _responseWaitHandle;

    private readonly Queue<IDispatchedRequest> _requestQueue
        = new Queue<IDispatchedRequest>();

    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer; // would resolve to System.Threading.Timer unqualified

    private readonly HashSet<IDispatchedRequest> _pendingHandlers
        = new HashSet<IDispatchedRequest>();

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ShopifyThrottleInfo> _throttleInfo
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ShopifyThrottleInfo>();

    private readonly bool _verbose;

    public RequestDispatcher(INotifierService notifier, int appId, string connectionString, double waitCutoff = 0.6, double? ticksPerSecond = null, bool outputJson = false)
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        TicksPerSecond = ticksPerSecond ?? Settings.Default.DispatcherTicksPerSecond;
        _notifier = notifier;
        _appId = appId;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _cutoff = waitCutoff;
        _verbose = outputJson;

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 / TicksPerSecond);
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public int PendingHandlers => _pendingHandlers.Count;
    public int PendingRequests => _requestQueue.Count;

    public void Pause() => _timer.Stop();
    public void Resume() => _timer.Start();

    private void WaitForPendingRequests() => _requestWaitHandle?.Wait();
    private void WaitForPendingHandlers() => _responseWaitHandle?.Wait();

    public void WaitForCompletion()
    {
        WaitForPendingRequests();
        WaitForPendingHandlers();
    }

    public void Enqueue<TAggregate, TWrapper, TEntity>(IDispatchedRequest<TAggregate, TWrapper, TEntity> request)
        where TWrapper : class, IEntityWrapper<TEntity>
        where TAggregate : class, IAggregateEntity<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (request == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

        _requestQueue.Enqueue(request);
        _pendingHandlers.Add(request);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _requestWaitHandle);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _responseWaitHandle);
        _logger.Debug($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Enqueued {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}); {_requestQueue.Count} requests enqueued");
    }

    public void Enqueue<TWrapper, TEntity>(IDispatchedRequest<TWrapper, TEntity> request)
        where TWrapper : class, IEntityWrapper<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (request == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

        _requestQueue.Enqueue(request);
        _pendingHandlers.Add(request);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _requestWaitHandle);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _responseWaitHandle);
        _logger.Debug($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Enqueued {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}); {_requestQueue.Count} requests enqueued");
    }

    public void Enqueue(IDispatchedRequest request)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (request == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

        _requestQueue.Enqueue(request);
        _pendingHandlers.Add(request);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _requestWaitHandle);
        IncrementWaitHandle(ref _responseWaitHandle);
        _logger.Debug($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Enqueued {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}); {_requestQueue.Count} requests enqueued");
    }

    private void IncrementWaitHandle(ref CountdownEvent handle)
    {
        if (handle == null)
        {
            handle = new CountdownEvent(1);
        }
        else if (handle.IsSet)
        {
            handle.Dispose();
            handle = new CountdownEvent(1);
        }
        else
        {
            handle.AddCount();
        }
    }

    private int _skippedTicks = 0;
    private bool ShouldSkip(string resource)
    {
        ShopifyThrottleInfo info;
        if (_throttleInfo.TryGetValue(resource, out info))
        {
            if (info.RetryAfter.TotalSeconds > 0)
            {
                // any premature request will be denied. insisting may get the API key disabled.
                return _skippedTicks < TicksPerSecond * info.RetryAfter.TotalSeconds;
            }

            // skip {TicksPerSeconds} ticks (1 second) if {_cutoff} % capacity is hit for this endpoint.
            return info.PercentCapacity > _cutoff && _skippedTicks < TicksPerSecond;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (_requestQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var next = _requestQueue.Peek();
        if (next == null)
        {
            _logger.Warn("Dequeued a null reference. Next up is a null request?? Dequeuing...");
            _requestQueue.Dequeue();
            return;
        }
        if (ShouldSkip(next.ResourceName))
        { 
            _skippedTicks++;
            _logger.Warn($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Skipped {_skippedTicks} dispatcher tick{(_skippedTicks > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty)}.");
            return;
        }

#pragma warning disable CS4014
        // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed.
        // ...that's the whole point...
        IssueNextRequest();
#pragma warning restore CS4014
    }

    private async Task IssueNextRequest()
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        _skippedTicks = 0;

        var request = GetNextRequest();
        Debug.Assert(request != null);

        dynamic response = null;
        try
        {
            // we can't bind T at compile-time for the generic Task<Response<T>>
            // so we bind it at run-time through a dynamic dispatch:
            var task = ((dynamic)request).Request.Invoke();
            response = task.Result; // response is Response<T>, where T is usually TAggregate, or TEntity otherwise.

            if (_verbose)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StringContent); // dynamic dispatch here
            }
            _logger.Info($"Successfully retrieved response from dispatched {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}).");

            if (response != null)
            {
                await HandleResponse(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Warn($"respone (request hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}) is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            if (!HandleApiException(request, e))
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _pendingHandlers.Remove(request);
            _responseWaitHandle.Signal();
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleResponse(IDispatchedRequest request, dynamic response)
    {
        ShopifyThrottleInfo throttleInfo = ResponseExtensions.GetThrottleInfo(response, request.ResourceName);

        _throttleInfo.AddOrUpdate(request.ResourceName, throttleInfo, (key, value) => throttleInfo);
        _logger.Debug($"Updated throttling info for {request.ResourceName}: {throttleInfo.Value}/{throttleInfo.Capacity} ({throttleInfo.PercentCapacity * 100}%)");

        try
        {
            _logger.Trace($"Handling response from dispatched {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode: {request.GetHashCode()})");
            await request.OnResponse(response);
        }
        finally
        {
            _logger.Trace($"Response of {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode: {request.GetHashCode()}) has been handled.");
            _logger.Debug($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Pending requests: {_requestQueue.Count}; pending handlers: {_pendingHandlers.Count}; wait handle counter: {_responseWaitHandle.CurrentCount}");
        }
    }

    private bool HandleApiException(IDispatchedRequest request, AggregateException e)
    {
        var handled = true; // caller will rethrow exception if method returns false.

        var apiExceptions = e.InnerExceptions.OfType<ApiException>();
        foreach (var exception in apiExceptions)
        {
            switch ((int)exception.StatusCode)
            {
                case 401: // unauthorized (verify authentication)
                case 403: // forbidden (verify permissions)
                    handled = false;
                    break;
                case 422: // unprocessable entity (e.g. posted fulfillment but line item was already fulfilled *LOG THIS*)
                    _logger.Warn(exception);
                    break;
                case 404: // not found (e.g. ShopifyID refers to non-existing resource *LOG THIS*)
                          // also returned by "fulfillments" endpoint (POST) if the specified location isn't active.
                    _logger.Warn(exception);
                    var postRequest = request as DispatchedPostRequest<FulfillmentWrapper, Fulfillment, FulfillmentPosting>;
                    if (postRequest != null)
                    {
                        NotifyFailedFulfillmentPosting(exception, postRequest);
                    }
                    break;
                case 429: // too many requests
                          // if this ApiException was thrown, tweak the throttling knobs...
                    _logger.Error(exception);
                    if (request.Retries < 3)
                    {
                        // todo log re-enqueued request
                        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                            .ContinueWith(_ =>
                            {
                                request.Retries++;
                                //Enqueue(request); // compiler can't resolve overload w/dynamic dispatch here
                                _requestQueue.Enqueue(request);
                                IncrementWaitHandle(ref _requestWaitHandle);
                            });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _notifier.Enqueue($"Failed to dispatch request {request.Retries} times (hashcode {request.GetHashCode()}). Request is aborted, data will be missing. Review logs for details.");
                    }
                    break;
            }

            _logger.Error(e);
        }
        return handled;
    }

    private IDispatchedRequest GetNextRequest()
    {
        var request = (IDispatchedRequest)null;
        try
        {
            request = _requestQueue.Dequeue();
            _requestWaitHandle.Signal();

            _logger.Debug($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Dequeued {request.ResourceName} request (hashcode: {request.GetHashCode()})");
            return request;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= OnTick;
        _timer.Dispose();

        _logger.Info($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} Disposing wait handle with {_requestQueue.Count} requests queued and {_pendingHandlers.Count} pending handlers.");

        _requestQueue.Clear();
        _requestWaitHandle?.Dispose();

        _pendingHandlers.Clear();
        _responseWaitHandle?.Dispose();

        _disposed = true;
    }

    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(RequestDispatcher));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've omitted the *failed fulfillment posting* stuff, which arguably belongs to another class.

How should I clean up the exception-handling code, and does anything else look like it could be improved?

Answer (score 2):

I get the sense that you might have a bit of thread-safety-related issues. Your code doesn't look totally comprehensive in that area. I might suggest a few minor tweaks.

The items that stand out to me are:

### HashSet

```
HashSet<IDispatchedRequest> _pendingHandlers;

// probably replace this with...
ConcurrentBag<IDispatchedRequest> _pendingHandlers;
```

In the case above, potentially running a unit test that sends multiple identical requests would throw an error in the `HashSet` as it has a unique constraint, and you also might run into a thread-safety issue too.

I also don't see a scenario where the `HashSet` is used beyond it being a generic collection. So, it looks like no harm to go with the `ConcurrentBag` option.

### Increment

```
_skippedTicks++;    // this doesn't look right to me

//replace it with somthing like this, or use a lock
Interlocked.Increment(ref _skippedTicks);
```

### Queue

```
Queue<IDispatchedRequest> _requestQueue; // may as well go concurrent here too
```

### Minor Comment

I can't quite put my finger on it, but generally when I see a series of methods working together that look like this:

```
private void Foo() { ... }
private async Task Bar() { ... }
```

I tend to question the design pattern **(i.e. what can we do to make methods return meaningful types and more test-friendly?)**. I haven't quite been able to digest the complexities with your scenario -- so I wish I had something more constructive to add here.